# do i need to use stripe listen - stripe cli in production?

Tags: python, stripe-payments

Is it required to run in command line:

```
stripe listen --forward-to localhost:5000/webhook
```

to receive stripe events to the webhook endpoint or does the endpoint automatically receive events if it is added to the stripe webhooks dashboard?

I'm trying to ask if `stripe listen` is used only for testing or is it needed in production?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> does the endpoint automatically receive events if it is added to the stripe webhooks dashboard?

yes. You only use stripe-cli so you can forward events to the local server on your machine that does not have a public URL. When you have a real server deployed and you set the endpoint in your Stripe webhook settings, Stripe send requests containing the Events to that webhook URl.
https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/go-live